# How to write a query instead of writing 6-9 different queries in SQL for JDBC in Java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I had written these 9 Queries in order to perform different operations

**GET_ITEMS** = "SELECT ITEM_ID,PART_NO,DESCRIPTION,SALE_PRICE,UPDATED_BY,UPDATED_DATE FROM ITEM ORDER BY
ITEM_ID";

**GET_ITEM_ID** = "SELECT ITEM_ID FROM ITEM ";

**GET_PART_NO** = "SELECT PART_NO FROM ITEM WHERE ITEM_ID=?";

**UPDATE_PART_NO** = "UPDATE ITEM SET PART_NO=? WHERE ITEM_ID= ?";

**GET_SALE_PRICE** = "SELECT SALE_PRICE FROM ITEM WHERE ITEM_ID=?";

**UPDATE_SALE_PRICE** = "UPDATE ITEM SET SALE_PRICE=? WHERE ITEM_ID=? ";

**GET_DESC** = "SELECT DESCRIPTION FROM ITEM WHERE ITEM_ID=?";

**UPDATE_DESC** = "UPDATE ITEM SET DESCRIPTION =?  WHERE ITEM_ID=?";

**INSERT_INTO_ITEMDUPLICATE** ="REPLACE INTO ITEM_DUPLICATE
(item_id,part_no,sale_price,description,barcode)SELECT
i.ITEM_ID,i.PART_NO,i.SALE_PRICE,i.DESCRIPTION,b.BARCODE FROM item i
JOIN item_barcode b ON b.ITEM_ID = i.ITEM_ID WHERE i.ITEM_ID = ?";

In my java JDBC program. But I want to write them as two queries one query for displaying data from DB and another for updating the data. Is it possible???. I am trying this in Eclipse using mySQL for DB.

Can any one please help regarding this I am trying to find a solution from 2 days

This is my console output, here at last if user give's Y then my data will be updated into item_duplicate table. For doing this I updated the item table as well. But I need to perform only updation in new table not in the item table.

Console output:

[image]

Comment: I am not clear what you are trying to do ALSO are you aware that you can update more than 1 column in an update by comma separating.

Comment: Hi, @P.Salmon
 ya I know that but the task is i need to ask user to select one field to update if user selects part_no then i should only perform update on part_no and update th evalue so for each and every field i have created different queries

Comment: user supplies item_id to be updated, the column name to update and the value the column to be updated to?

Comment: item_id is primary key so it cannot be updated, remaining three can be updated. and the value was given  by user itself and it should be updated to same column name in item_duplicaet table.@P.Salmon

Answer (score 0):

> But I want to write them as two queries one query for displaying data from DB and another for updating the data. Is it possible???

The first query will "display data" from ITEM, so that's fine, and yes, you can write another single query which updates data (though it'll probably need to be built up in parts in your java code depending on which field(s) have changed)

eg (written, not compiled):

```
string queryPrefix = "UPDATE ITEM SET ";
string querySuffix = " WHERE ITEM_ID=?";

List<String> queryUpdates = new ArrayList<String>;
List<object> queryParameters = new ArrayList<object>;

if (updatePartNumber) { 
  queryUpdates.add("PART_NO=?");
  queryParameters.add(newPartNumber);
}
if (updateSalePrice) { 
  queryUpdates.add("SALE_PRICE=?");
  queryParameters.add(newSalePrice);
}
// etc

string query = queryPrefix + String.join(",",queryUpdates) + querySuffix;
queryParameters.Add(itemId);
```

However, your final query is a different thing entirely, and i can't see how to mix that into the logic above.

Comment: Hi @mcdrewski Thank you for your suggestion, can you explain me in detail about this String.join(",",queryUpdates). am new to coding and java so if you can expalin what that particular part does it will be help full. Now comming to if (updatePartNumber) where can we give this updatePartNumber as a variable so that it redirects to this if clause. Thank you.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-